# Data category - on click modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is a way to add new data-category to existing one once click event would happen?
I want to add it since I am using it as a filtering element.

An example below: Click the button and add the category: Delta

```html
<div class="item" data-category="Alfa , Beta , Gamma "> 

<p> Object 1<p>

<div>

<button class="my-fav">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get attributes of the element and change it then set it again, here is an example:

```
<div id="data" class="item" data-category="Alfa , Beta , Gamma "> 
    <p> Object 1<p>
</div>
<button id="myButton" class="my-fav">

<script>
    const data = document.getElementById("data");
    const button = document.getElementById("myButton");

    let data_attribute = data.getAttribute("data-category");

    myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        data_attribute += ", Delta";
        data.setAttribute("data-category", data_attribute);
    });
</script>
```